# Why doesn't this produce an overflow exception?

Tags: c#, overflowexception

I was testing something out using LinqPad and was surprised that the following code did not produce an exception:

```
ulong lSmallValue = 5;
ulong lBigValue = 10;

ulong lDifference = lSmallValue - lBigValue;

Console.WriteLine(lDifference);
Console.WriteLine((long)lDifference);
```

This produces the following output:

```
18446744073709551611
-5
```

Fortunately, I was hoping for this behavior, but I was under the assumption that this would cause an `OverflowException` to be thrown.

From [`System.OverflowException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception.aspx):

> An OverflowException is thrown at run time under the following conditions:
>
> - An arithmetic operation produces a result that is outside the range of the data type returned by the operation.
> - A casting or conversion operation attempts to perform a narrowing conversion, and the value of the source data type is outside the range of the target data type.

Why doesn't the operation `lSmallValue - lBigValue` fall into the first category?

Comment: Probably it is _not_ outside the range; the `ulong` still has enough _bits_ to hold the values of your operation (although it is interpreted different to what you expect).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CLR will not throw the Overflow exception by default. Unless you're using the "checked" keyword.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

UPD: Actually, I do recommend the "CLR via C#" by Jeffrey Richter - he makes these things so much more transparent. My favorite book about the CLR and C# fundamentals.

Comment: This does in-fact cause the exception to be thrown. Thanks, I've never run into the `checked` keyword before.

Answer (score 0):

"For the arithmetic, casting, or conversion operation to throw an OverflowException, the operation must occur in a checked context."

The OverflowException will be called as soon as you put your code within a checked block.

```
ulong lSmallValue = 5;
ulong lBigValue = 10;
checked {
try {
    ulong lDifference = lSmallValue - lBigValue;
}
catch (OverflowException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
}}
```

Comment: This is wrong, if I wrap it in a try..catch block in LinqPad still no exception is thrown.

Comment: "Checked" in this case has nothing to do with try/catch.  There is a `checked { }` block, iirc, that turns on overflow checking.

Comment: I don't think that this is a correct answer - try catch doesn't make any sense there. You need to use the "cehcked" keyword. See my response lower

Comment: -1 This is wrong. Checked context has nothing to do with try/catch and everything to do with being run within a `checked` block. `unchecked` context is the default.

Comment: I'm not getting any exceptions when that code is inside a try..catch block.

Comment: Oops, of course. The checked context is required. I adapted the text.