# List(Of T) saved by unknown hero?

Tags: .net, vb.net

> ***What prevents a `List(Of T)` from throwing an arithmetic overflow exception when I set the internal `_version` field to `Integer.MaxValue` and add a new item?***

---

*TL;DR:*

As you can see when looking at the source code there's no protection against the potential arithmetic overflow. But some-one/thing is setting the value to `Integer.MinValue` if the value is maximum.

```
<__DynamicallyInvokable()> _
Public Sub Add(ByVal item As T)
    If (Me._size = Me._items.Length) Then
        Me.EnsureCapacity((Me._size + 1))
    End If
    Me._items(Me._size++) = item
    Me._version += 1
End Sub
```

---

*Detailed*

As the internal item-array of [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) is private, and I wouldn't use reflection to access it, I decided to create a custom list using the original [List(Of T)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) source code.

However, I noticed that there were no protection against a potential arithmetic overflow if the version ever reached [Integer.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Me._version += 1
```

So I modified the code:

```
Me._version = If((Me._version = Integer.MaxValue), Integer.MinValue, (Me._version + 1I))
```

Now begins the fun part; Out of curiosity, I set up a test where I used reflection to set the internal `_version` field to max.

```
Dim flags As BindingFlags = (BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
Dim list As New List(Of String)
Dim _version As FieldInfo = GetType(List(Of String)).GetField("_version", flags)

_version.SetValue(list, Integer.MaxValue)
Debug.WriteLine("Count: {0}, Version: {1}", list.Count, _version.GetValue(list))
list.Add("str")
Debug.WriteLine("Count: {0}, Version: {1}", list.Count, _version.GetValue(list))
```

I was shocked by the results:

> Count: 0, Version: 2147483647
> Count: 1, Version: -2147483648

There's nothing in the source code that sets the field to minimum if maximum is reached. I even looked at the [DynamicallyInvokable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550749/what-is-the-dynamicallyinvokable-attribute-for) attribute, but as far as I can tell it's not relevant.

```
<__DynamicallyInvokable()> _
Public Sub Add(ByVal item As T)
    If (Me._size = Me._items.Length) Then
        Me.EnsureCapacity((Me._size + 1))
    End If
    Me._items(Me._size++) = item
    Me._version += 1
End Sub

Private Sub EnsureCapacity(ByVal min As Integer)
    If (Me._items.Length < min) Then
        Dim num As Integer = IIf((Me._items.Length = 0), 4, (Me._items.Length * 2))
        If (num > &H7FEFFFFF) Then
            num = &H7FEFFFFF
        End If
        If (num < min) Then
            num = min
        End If
        Me.Capacity = num
    End If
End Sub

<__DynamicallyInvokable()> _
Public Property Capacity As Integer
    <TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries"), __DynamicallyInvokable()> _
    Get
        Return Me._items.Length
    End Get
    <__DynamicallyInvokable()> _
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        If (value < Me._size) Then
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity)
        End If
        If (value <> Me._items.Length) Then
            If (value > 0) Then
                Dim destinationArray As T() = New T(value - 1) {}
                If (Me._size > 0) Then
                    Array.Copy(Me._items, 0, destinationArray, 0, Me._size)
                End If
                Me._items = destinationArray
            Else
                Me._items = List(Of T)._emptyArray
            End If
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12571516/242520

Comment: reflection is a great tool to introduce bugs. Is that your intention? ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you read the "detailed section" in my question you'll see that I've created a custom list to *avoid* using reflection. And by custom I mean from scratch, not inheriting.

Comment: Also: Why did I use reflection? Well, because I didn't want to change the list `2,147,483,647` times just to see what happens when I add a new item to the list when the internal `_version` is set to `Int32.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The base class library is written in C#, not in VB.NET.

By default, arithmetic operations in C# do not throw overflow exceptions. Instead, they silently wrap the value around, as you have noticed.

This decision was probably made for reasons of efficiency; not everyone agrees with it. More information can be found in the following questions:

- [Why doesn't C# use arithmetic overflow checking by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259408/87698)
- [Why don't languages raise errors on integer overflow by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/103654/87698)

Comment: For the record, I do know it's written in `C#`. However, I just didn't expect such radical difference between how `C#` and `vb.net` arithmetic operations work.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Yes, there are a few unexpected gotchas when working with both C# and VB.NET. [`null` and `Nothing` not being the same](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/nothing-vs-null.html) is another one of them.